# Streams API :: How do i modify the variables of my custom object from a LIST<Object>?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

1.I am getting a List of Objects form Database Containing Fields as per my pojo..
List fieldList==>Contains the List of Objects...>

```
List<Object> fieldList;
for(Object abc: fieldList){
                    abc.setIdMongoStr("RoleName");
                    abc.setTenantRegion("RoleNumber");
                }
```

How do i convert it Stream ????

Comment: `fieldList.stream().map(//Map here to your pojo).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: **multiple-pojo*** how to do it???????

Comment: @RajatDiwate Avoid mutating the objects while `Stream`ing them. You could call an update method for the entities withing `forEach` as well, but the `for(:)` loop is far more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to set the same value to each item and thats all, you can use directly foreach, here is an example:

```
fieldList.stream().forEach(field -> {
            field.setIdMongoStr("RoleName");
            field.setTenantRegion("RoleNumber");
        });
```

This will mutate directly your objects inside the list

Comment: nope!! value changes each time(thats seperate logic)!!

Comment: @RajatDiwate this stream does exactly the same as your foreach (with only difference it mutates the list) from the question, please give more information in order to get a proper response, cheers

Comment: You even don't need `.stream()`. Collections do have `.forEach` method.

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko the question was "How do i convert it Stream ????"

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus, no need to convert Collection to Stream in this particular case. Just put `fieldList.forEach(field -> { ... });` Since Java 8 `forEach` method is a part of `Iterable` interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Using Stream will be an overkill for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
//replce it with your db result 
List<Object> yourlistOfObject=new ArrayList<Object>();

// convert inside the map() method directly.
List<YourObject> result = yourlistOfObject.stream().map(temp -> {
              YourObject obj = new YourObject();
              obj.setName(temp.getName());
              obj.setAge(temp.getAge());
              return obj;
          }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *New object Creation* it affects performance??? ,,```fieldList.stream().map(//Map here to your pojo).collect(Collectors.toList());``` cant we do it in this